# Powershell: null file always generated (output of Compare-Object)

Tags: windows, powershell, file, compare, member-enumeration

The most popular answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338097/remove-lines-from-file1-that-exist-in-file2-in-powershell) involves the following Windows powershell code (edited to fix a bug):

```
$file1 = Get-Content C:\temp\file1.txt  
$file2 = Get-Content C:\temp\file2.txt   
$Diff = Compare-Object $File1 $File2  
$LeftSide = ($Diff | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='}).InputObject  
$LeftSide | Set-Content C:\temp\file3.txt
```

I always get a zero byte file as the output, even if I remove the $Diff line.

Why is the output file always null, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Are we expected to know, why you'd expect anything else, or what that would be?

Comment: Regardless of the input files, the output is always null.

Comment: I get content in file3.txt using your sample.

Comment: @Burt_Harris Thanks. Could it be a Powershell version issue?  I need to support v2.

Comment: It could be!  That's pretty old now, I don't see any obvious problems, but if I had to guess it the next-to-last line that looks fragile.

Comment: Member enumeration is v3+ feature. Thus `($Diff | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='}).InputObject` will only work when `$Diff | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='}` produce exactly one item.

Answer (score 6):

[PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral), as he routinely does, has provided the crucial pointer in a comment on the question:

[***Member-access enumeration***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) - the ability to access a member (a property or a method) on a *collection* and have it implicitly applied to *each of its elements*, with the results getting collected in an *array*, was [introduced in **PSv3**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2012/06/13/new-v3-language-features/).<sup>[1]</sup>

Member-access enumeration is not only **expressive and convenient**, it is also ***faster* than alternative approaches**.

A simplified example:

```bash
PS> ((Get-Item /), (Get-Item $HOME)).Mode
d--hs-   # The value of (Get-Item /).Mode
d-----   # The value of (Get-Item $HOME).Mode
```

Applying `.Mode` to the *collection* that the `(...)`-enclosed command outputs causes the `.Mode` property to be accessed on *each item in the collection*, with the resulting values returned *as an array* (a regular PowerShell array, of type`[System.Object[]]`).

*Caveats*: Member-access enumeration handles the resulting array like the *pipeline* does, which means:

- If the array has only a *single* element, that element's property value is returned *directly*, not inside a single-element array:

  ```bash
    PS> @([pscustomobject] @{foo=1}).foo.GetType().Name
    Int32  # 1 was returned as a scalar, not as a single-element array.
  ```
- If the property values being collected are *themselves* arrays, a *flat* array of values is returned:

  ```bash
    PS> @([pscustomobject] @{foo=1,2}, [pscustomobject] @{foo=3,4}).foo.Count
    4 # a single, flat array was returned: 1, 2, 3, 4
  ```

Also, member-access enumeration **only works for *getting* (reading) property values, not for *setting* (writing) them**.
[This asymmetry is by design](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5271), to avoid potentially unwanted bulk modification; in PSv4+, **use `.ForEach('<property-name', <new-value>)`** as the quickest workaround (see below).

---

This convenient feature is **NOT available**, however:

- if you're running on **PSv2** (categorically)
- **if the *collection itself* has a member by the specified name**, in which case the collection-level member is applied.

For instance, even in PSv3+ the following does NOT perform member-access enumeration:

```bash
    PS> ('abc', 'cdefg').Length  # Try to report the string lengths
    2 # !! The *array's* .Length property value (item count) is reported, not the items'
```

In such cases - and in **PSv2** in general - a different approach is needed:

- **Fastest** alternative, using the **`foreach` *statement***, assuming that the entire collection fits into memory as a whole (which is *implied* when using member-access enumeration).

```bash
PS> foreach ($s in 'abc', 'cdefg') { $s.Length }
3
5
```

- **PSv4+** alternative, using *collection method* `.ForEach()`, also operating on the collection as a whole:

```bash
PS> ('abc', 'cdefg').ForEach('Length')
3
5
```

<sup>Note: If applicable to the input collection, you can also *set* property values with `.ForEach('<prop-name>', <new-value>)`, which is the fastest workaround to not being able to use `.<prop-name> = <new-value>`, i.e. the inability to *set* property values with member-access enumeration.</sup>

- **Slowest, but memory-efficient** approaches, using the **pipeline**:

Note: Use of the pipeline is only memory-efficient if you process the items one by one, in isolation, without collecting the results in memory as well.

Using the `ForEach-Object` *cmdlet*, as in [Burt Harris' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44611185/45375):

```bash
PS> 'abc', 'cdefg' | ForEach-Object { $_.Length }
3
5
```

For properties only (as opposed to methods), `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` is an option; it is conceptually clear and simple, and virtually on par with the `ForEach-Object` approach in terms of performance (for a performance comparison, see the last section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48888108/45375)):

```bash
PS> 'abc', 'cdefg' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Length
3
5
```

---

<sup>[1] Previously, the feature was semi-officially known as just *member enumeration*, introduced in [this 2012 blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/new-v3-language-features/) along with the feature itself. A decision to formally introduce the term *member-access enumeration* was [made in early 2022](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/8437#issuecomment-1064258293).</sup>

Comment: You should make a powershell dictionary (*I say powershell since some meanings, mean different things in some programming languages*). Definitely would be a hot seller lots of us would advertise and buy! I struggle with lots of this stuff and the MS documentation can come off a bit confusing, and your explanations make it a lot easier to understand. 10/10 would buy! @Santiago Squarzon, back me up on this... lol

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps instead of

```
$LeftSide = ($Diff | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='}).InputObject
```

PowerShell 2 might work better with:

```
$LeftSide = $Diff | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='} | 
            Foreach-object { $_.InputObject }
```